# SSH issues on centos

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to switch all of my servers to ssh key auth logins. I have it working with some servers but for what ever reason my new centos server is not working correctly.

I am on windows and using putty.

I have enabled key auth in the sshd_config and restarted it.

I also have denied root logins and created a new user that I can log in with using a password.

I am logging in to the server with that user, creating a .ssh folder in my ~ dir and then creating an authorized_keys file can copying in my key. I then chmod the .ssh dir 700 and then the file 640.

I try to log in and get a rejected key message and then the password entry.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my sshd_config https://gist.github.com/alexhackney/64a4c99b993505a9e44f
Here is the secure log https://gist.github.com/alexhackney/90319feb853e18a2fd48

I ran the tail on secure then logged in and out on another window and ran the command again.

Comment: first you need to give more information, log files and config

Comment: what log file do I need to look at?

Comment: `/var/log/secure` for starters. Check your `${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys` if it matches the key loaded in PuTTY. Check that the format is correct.

Comment: And this should be in the home for the user not root correct?

Comment: When I check the secure log there is no entry about the key.

Comment: As @fuero said, check the format of your authorized_keys file. Your key should be on one line, in "openssh" format. You cannot just copy/paste the native putty key format.

Comment: I have this same setup working on laravel forge servers. I'm not using the putty output one, I converted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the home directory of the new user is set to read/write for that user only (i.e. permission of 700).  It's not enough for the .ssh directory to be 700 -- the home directory needs to be 700 too.  Also, I don't think the argument to AuthorizedKeysFile needs the ~/ before .ssh/authorized_keys.  My systems work fine without it.

Comment: The user directory is correctly set to 700

Comment: The ~ in the AuthorizedKeysFile directive was the problem. Thank you.